Can auto be used for static class variable definition?
Consider this simple example:
struct Class {
    struct Inner {};
    static Inner a;
};

I cannot define this a with this syntax:
auto Class::a = Inner{}; - gcc and msvc both complaint in a similar ways:
<source>:9:6: error: conflicting declaration 'auto Class::a'
    9 | auto Class::a = Inner{};
      |      ^~~~~
<source>:6:18: note: previous declaration as 'Class::Inner Class::a'
    6 |     static Inner a;
      |                  ^

but clang accepts this code.
Of course the reason for this syntax is to not repeat Class:: twice:
Class::Inner Class::a{};
So, the question - is it correct (clang is right) or incorrect (gcc and msvc are right)?

gcc and MSVC are right according to the accepted answer here. But note that that post is more than 10 years old and the post refers to C++11, there might have been some changes since then.

@wohlstad Most recent wording is there. AFAIU (not very far ;) ): auto can basically be find in a declaration context, not a definition one. Compilers diagnostic seem to go this way (https://godbolt.org/z/8qM19T345 and op question): they see a (re)declaration.

It's core issue #2389. Clang is right, the code is valid.

2389. Agreement of deduced and explicitly-specified variable types
Section: 9.2.9.7  [dcl.spec.auto]   Status: CD6   Submitter: Nina
Ranns   Date: 2018-10-24
The Standard does not explicitly address whether an example like the
following is well-formed or not:
struct S {
  static int i;
};
auto S::i = 23;

There is implementation divergence on the handling of this example.
Notes from the July, 2019 meeting
Editorially add the example as well-formed; see editorial issue 2979.
CWG 2019-09-16
Approved editorial change 3227.

It has already been applied to C++20 as can be seen in [dcl.spec.auto.general]/p13.
Being a CD6 status (CD6: A DR/DRWP or Accepted/WP issue not resolved in C++20 but included in the Committee Draft advanced for balloting at the July, 2022 WG21 meeting), it appears that GCC hasn't implemented it yet.
